# Issue with mathematica vector file

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, vector-graphics

Hi I am using Mathematica student versions to draw some 3D crystal structures.

From there I want to save the images as vector files (.eps or .pdf) and later edit those files in Adobe Illustrator or similar platform.
However, I am facing a difficulty that the images are not getting saved as vector files instead they are getting saved as bitmap files.
Do you have any solutions to this?

Thanks in advance!

I am trying to expoprt the formed image.